# How to get status information from hostapd?

Tags: hostapd, virtual-wifi

I want to get status information from hostapd.
I want to know how many wifi-devices connected, what is mac address, ip and session for each device.
It will be nice to get notification if new user connected.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 5):

Old post but if someone is searching ...

You can use `hostapd_cli`. 
You can also use `cat /var/log/syslog | grep hostapd`.

You can change the debug level in starting script `/etc/init.d/hostapd`. 
Adding `-d` or `-dd` in this file will add more information in `/var/log/syslog`.